# Monit logs running process as server not running

Tags: monitoring, monitor, monit

I'm trying to monitor my server and just want to restart it when its down. Following is my monit control

```
check process myserver with pidfile "/home/path/to/myserver.pid"
start program = "/etc/init.d/myserver start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/myserver stop"
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 8080 protocol http
then restart
```

But even if the server is running monit gives error like:

```
'myserver' process not running
trying to restart 'myserver'
failed to restart myserver.
```

How do I fix this? Am I making some mistakes?

Also when I try to use 'send' and 'expect' it gives error like

```
Erro: syntax error 'send'.
```

Comment: did you try with check process myserver with pidfile /home/path/to/myserver.pid
i.e. without the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to specify UID and GID as monit runs as root.

```
check process myserver 
  with pidfile "/home/path/to/myserver.pid"
  start program = "/etc/init.d/myserver start"
    as uid myserver_uid and gid myserver_gid
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/myserver stop"
    as uid myserver_uid and gid myserver_gid
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 8080 protocol http
then restart
```

To debug, you could try to output to a file and check this file to have more details.

```
check process myserver 
  with pidfile "/home/path/to/myserver.pid"
  start program = "/etc/init.d/myserver start >> /tmp/myserver.log 2>&1"
    as uid myserver_uid and gid myserver_gid
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/myserver stop  >> /tmp/myserver.log 2>&1"
    as uid myserver_uid and gid myserver_gid
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 8080 protocol http
then restart
```

For the send and expect, you might not need it for http query as the http protocol is supported.